# Value from table to <select> -> <option>

Tags: php, html

How I can insert values from database to `<select> -> <option>` in HTML?

Example:

I have table with `ID_class` and `name of class`. And I would like to user can choose `<option>` with value `name of class`.

```
<select>
   <option>VALUE FROM TABLE</option>
   ...
</select>
```

I work with PDO and jQuery.

Comment: If you're working with PDO there should be PDO code here, and there's none.

Comment: Yea, 'cause I dont know how i'll do it.

Comment: You're going to have to make an attempt, though. We can't help you write the code from scratch, but we can help you fix something that's missing small parts or has relatively simple problems.

Comment: I made a loop, that was finding count of values in table and was creating `<option>` based on the count of values, but it did not work.

Comment: Ok, I get it. But how I can save some row to variable? `var option_value = "<?php echo($result[" + i + "]); ?>"`?

Comment: If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious where you're getting stuck, but here are some snippets to help out.

First of all, your `select` needs a name and `option`s need a value, so that the selected value can be accessed on the server side.

```
<select name='chooser'>
  <option value='name-1'>...</option>
  <option value='name-2'>...</option>
</select>
```

On the server side, your query should look something like this using PDO:

```
$insertData = $con->prepare('
    INSERT INTO your_table
    VALUES(
        DEFAULT,
        :name,
    )
');
// the value of $_POST['chooser'] here is the value of the selected option (e.g. "name-2")
$insertData->bindValue('name', $_POST['chooser'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insertData->execute();
```